# RegEx for matching variable parts in then string

Tags: c#, regex, performance

I have a list of more than 100 message and I need to identify a particular message and its occurrence.

For this purpose, I have created a ***regex lookup*** to match these ***random messages*** by placing `*` at the variable section of the message as below:

> CheckConvexity: Zone=`*`, Surface=`*` is non-convex.  ...vertex `*` to
>   vertex `*` to vertex `*`  ...vertex `*`=[`*`]  ...vertex `*`=[`*`]  ...vertex
>   `*`=[`*`]

Later I substitute regex pattern quantifiers/literals on the place of `*` to make it work but matching 1000 messages with 1000 lookup regex string takes too much time:

> `CheckConvexity:\ Zone=.*,\ Surface=.*\ is\ non-convex\.\ \`
>   `\.\.\.vertex\ .*\ to\ vertex\ .*\ to\ vertex\ .*\ \ \.\.\.vertex\`
>   `.*=\[.*\]\ \ \.\.\.vertex\ .*=\[.*\]\ \ \.\.\.vertex\ .*=\[.*\]`

Running example: https://regex101.com/r/pX9jvD/1

Later I have replaced `.*` with `[^ ]*` but it only matches variable section until any space occurs so it fails for more of the messages. This way pattern matching was too much fast and messages are parsed with lighting speed.

let my message is as below, then what should be the regex pattern for the variable section of the string which matches any character with impacting the performance of the pattern matching:

> "CheckConvexity: Zone=CEILING VOID ZONE STORY 1, Surface=CEILING VOID
>   STAFF BEDROOM:SLAB 2.2 is non-convex.  ...vertex 2 to vertex 3 to
>   vertex 4  ...vertex 2=[-9.59,21.59,3.90]  ...vertex
>   3=[-6.73,24.45,3.90]  ...vertex 4=[-8.13,25.85,3.90]"

Below is the example code snippet to parse in different ways:

```
public class CalculateRegexProcessingTime
{
    public void GetRegexTimeCaculations()
    {
        string patternString = "CheckConvexity: Zone=*, Surface=* is non-convex.  ...vertex * to vertex * to vertex *  ...vertex *=[*]  ...vertex *=[*]  ...vertex *=[*]";
        patternString = Regex.Escape(patternString);
        if (patternString.Contains("\\*]"))
            patternString = patternString.Replace("\\*]", "\\*\\]");

        string sampleMsgToMatch = "CheckConvexity: Zone=CEILING VOID ZONE STORY 1, Surface=CEILING VOID STAFF BEDROOM:SLAB 2.2 is non-convex.  ...vertex 2 to vertex 3 to vertex 4  ...vertex 2=[-9.59,21.59,3.90]  ...vertex 3=[-6.73,24.45,3.90]  ...vertex 4=[-8.13,25.85,3.90]";
        MatchRegExGreedyPattern(patternString, sampleMsgToMatch);
        MatchRegExWithBoundaryConditon(patternString, sampleMsgToMatch);
        MatchRegExWithLazyPattern(patternString, sampleMsgToMatch);
    }

    private void MatchRegExGreedyPattern(string patternString, string sampleMsgToMatch)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Greedy method");
        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();
        patternString = patternString.Replace("\\*", ".*");
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Pattern:{0}", patternString));
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Matched:{0}", Regex.IsMatch(sampleMsgToMatch, patternString, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace)));
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Parse Time:{0} sec", watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds));

    }

    private void MatchRegExWithBoundaryConditon(string patternString, string sampleMsgToMatch)
    {
        //It is failing to match becuase msg contain space between variable section of message, 
        // Need to correct it but what should be the conditions to make it generic
        Console.WriteLine("Matching RegEx with Boundary Conditon");
        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();
        patternString = patternString.Replace("\\*", "[^ ]*");
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Pattern:{0}", patternString));
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Matched:{0}", Regex.IsMatch(sampleMsgToMatch, patternString, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace)));
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Parse Time:{0} sec", watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds));
    }

    private void MatchRegExWithLazyPattern(string patternString, string sampleMsgToMatch)
    {
        //It is failing to match becuase msg contain space between variable section of message, 
        // Need to correct it but what should be the conditions to make it generic
        Console.WriteLine("Matching RegEx with Lazy pattern matching");
        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();
        patternString = patternString.Replace("\\*", "[^$]*");
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Pattern:{0}", patternString));
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Matched:{0}", Regex.IsMatch(sampleMsgToMatch, patternString, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace)));
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Parse Time:{0} sec", watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds));
    }
}
```

Comment: Check https://regex101.com/r/pX9jvD/2. If your string are all like this, just using lazy quantifier will make the pattern more efficient in this scenario.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I have checked but not much dramatic changes in performance. See lowest one is the result of `.*?` replacement.
`Greedy method
Matched:True
Parse Time:0.000418 sec
Matching RegEx with Boundary Conditon
Matched:False
Parse Time:0.0000869 sec
Matching RegEx with Lazy pattern matching
Matched:True
Parse Time:0.0001095 sec
Matching RegEx with Lazy pattern matching 1
Matched:True
Parse Time:0.0000796 sec`

Comment: I have tried `.*?` also in the real application and it is better than .* but there was not much performance improvement observed. It there any much performance efficient replacement as like `[^ ]*` improved version??

Comment: Only if you write the pattern by hand. Then, you can optimize.

Comment: But these variable names are not finite and can not be specified with some boundaries of specific characters otherwise it will be better to set boundaries for pattern..

Comment: So, the only way is using `.`, yes. If you want to do it with regex. Else, you may use wildcard search. See [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30299838/3832970).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I have tested it but it too much slow rather than regex and not near to regex. It does not escape special characters.

Comment: Then lazy `.*?` are your only chance. And if you have `.*?` at the end of the pattern, always remove `?`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Thanks.. Then I have to revert my regex back to `.?*`..:)

Comment: You meant `.*?`

Comment: Yes.. Last time I found it better than `.*` so it is the only way to find variable part of the message then I will stick with it. Thanks