# Search for string with few missing characters

Tags: c#, algorithm, search

I have a big array of strings (characters a-z, A-Z and digits 0-9). I also have an input string, but few characters are missing (Example: /np/tSt/ing/), '/' represents missing character. I have to find every string from my array who can be formed from input string by replacing '/' with any character (Example: inputString1, AnpAtStAngA, 1np2tSt3ing4...). Is there any non brute-force solution for this problem?

Comment: This is called a wildcard.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matching strings with wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30299671/matching-strings-with-wildcard)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use regular expressions for this. Something like `.np.tSt.ing.`

```
public static Regex regex = new Regex(".np.tSt.ing.", RegexOptions.CultureInvariant | RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

...

```
bool IsMatch = regex.IsMatch(InputText);
```

Comment: Working perfectly!