# Checking if string contains pattern, with places ignored. And returning the index from which the items match

Tags: c#, regex

I have implemented such a method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string s = "05 AA 06 15 14";
    var pattern1 = "05 AA";
    var pattern2 = "06 15";
    var pattern3 = "AA ** 15";
    var pattern4 = "15 14";
    Console.WriteLine(CheckTextContains2(s, pattern1));
    Console.WriteLine(CheckTextContains2(s, pattern2));
    Console.WriteLine(CheckTextContains2(s, pattern3));
    Console.WriteLine(CheckTextContains2(s, pattern4));
}
private static int CheckTextContains2(string text, string pattern)
{
    if (text.Length < pattern.Length)
        return -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < text.Length - pattern.Length +1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < pattern.Length; j++)
        {
            if (pattern[j] == '*')
                continue;
            else if (text[j + i] != pattern[j])
                break;
            else if (j == pattern.Length -1)
                return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

The method checks if the given pattern is in the string, but ignore chars "*" and return start index.

But it seems terribly suboptimal, Can I getting it by regex?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matching strings with wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30299671/matching-strings-with-wildcard)

Comment: @Sinatr No, in my case '*' ignore only one char. And I need know start index.

Comment: Yes. You can use `Regex.Match(s, pattern)` to check for position. The only change in `pattern3` is that you have to replace `*` by `.`. [DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8QZ2wR) A sample line that looks for a position might look like `var posP1 = Regex.Match(s, pattern1) is { Success: true } m1 ? m1.Index : -1;`

Comment: @SebastianSchumann: A great answer. Too bad that the OP won't be able to accept it since you accidentally posted it into the comment field...

Comment: @Heinzi It wasn't accidentally posted as a comment. This was intended. I hoped that someone took the idea and add a bit of context information arround that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can use `Regex.Match(s, pattern)` to check for position. The only change in pattern3 is that you have to replace `*` by `.`.

The code might look like this:

```
string s = "05 AA 06 15 14";
var pattern1 = "05 AA";
var pattern2 = "06 15";
var pattern3 = "AA .. 15";
var pattern4 = "15 14";

var posP1 = Regex.Match(s, pattern1) is { Success: true } m1 ? m1.Index : -1;
var posP2 = Regex.Match(s, pattern2) is { Success: true } m2 ? m2.Index : -1;
var posP3 = Regex.Match(s, pattern3) is { Success: true } m3 ? m3.Index : -1;
var posP4 = Regex.Match(s, pattern4) is { Success: true } m4 ? m4.Index : -1;

Console.WriteLine(posP1);
Console.WriteLine(posP2);
Console.WriteLine(posP3);
Console.WriteLine(posP4);
```

The output is:

```
0
6
3
9
```

[DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8QZ2wR)

Explanation:

A `.` in regex is a single character wildcard. All the other characters in your pattern doesn't affect the regex and will be used as fixed text to find. You have to be a bit carefully about chars like `\[]{}.()*+`. But if your pattern doesn't contain any of those regex will work like `string.IndexOf()`.

The `Regex.Match()` method will return a `Match` instance that contains a property that has to be checked for `Success`. The sample code does it using pattern matching to be able to write it in one line.

Keep in mind that you should cache the regexes with `this._pattern1Finder = new Regex(pattern1, RegexOptions.Compiled)` to avoid the regex construction at every execution. The call will look like `this._pattern1Finder.Match(s) is { ...` instead of using the static Methods of `Regex`. This depends on how often you try to match the same patterns against various inputs.

Answer (score 0):

If the contest is: the-shorter-the-better, I'd like to introduce:

```
private static int CheckTextContains(string text, string pattern)
    {
        if (text.Length >= pattern.Length) {
            for (var offset = 0; offset < text.Length - pattern.Length; offset++) {
                if (!pattern.Where((t, i) => '*' != t && t != text[i + offset]).Any())
                    return offset;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

which is a condensed and not really well-readable and maintainable version of:

```
private static int CheckTextContains(string text, string pattern)
    {
        if (text.Length >= pattern.Length) {
            for (var offset = 0; offset < text.Length - pattern.Length; offset++) {
                if (IsMatch(offset))
                    return offset;
            }
        }
        return -1;

        bool IsMatch(int offset) {
            for (var i = 0; i < pattern.Length; i++)
            {
                if ('*' != pattern[i] && pattern[i] != text[i+offset]))
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```